# How should I go about rewriting this code to pull specific posts on my Invision power board from a separate application in java?

Tags: java, regex, multithreading

What I am planning on doing is pulling the first post of my news section, this was made for V bulletin and now I need to add it for IPb.

```
         package com.rigory.loader.main.services;

            import java.io.BufferedReader;
            import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
            import java.io.InputStreamReader;
            import java.net.MalformedURLException;
            import java.net.URL;
            import java.util.ArrayList;
            import java.util.List;
            import java.util.regex.Matcher;
            import java.util.regex.Pattern;

            import com.rigory.loader.main.gui.MainFrame;
            import com.rigory.loader.main.gui.SplashScreen;
            import com.rigory.loader.main.services.data.ThreadData;
            public class LatestThread {
```

String to VBulletin

```
            private final String WEBSITE_URL ="http://rigory.com/forums/forum/8-news-and-announcements/";
```

Regex search Thread Name

```
            private final String REGEX_THREAD_NAMES = "<font color=\"#0099FF\"><strong>(.*?)</a> ";
```

Regex search Thread URL

```
            private final String REGEX_THREAD_URL = "border=\"0\" /> <a href=\"(.*)\">1</a>";
```

Regex search Thread Content (this used to be a developer font color in an HTML element, now we have it stored as a css element

> div > div.post_body > div.group_4.post.entry-content > p:nth-child(1)

```
            private final String REGEX_THREAD_CONTENT ="<div class=\"blizzquote\">(.*)";
```

This variable is the index of your latest news post

```
        private final int THREADINDEX = 3;

        private SplashScreen splash;

        public LatestThread(SplashScreen splash){
            this.splash = splash;
        }
        public List<ThreadData> getData(){
            List<ThreadData> out = new ArrayList<ThreadData>();
            try{
                URL url = new URL(WEBSITE_URL);
                BufferedReader reader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                String inputLine;
                int count = 0;
                while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null  && count < THREADINDEX) {
                    ThreadData in = getDetails(inputLine);
                    if(in != null){
                        out.add(in);
                        count++;
                        this.splash.getProgressBar().setValue(this.splash.getProgressBar().getValue() + 33);
                        this.splash.getDescLbl().setText("Loading News Data.");
                        this.splash.repaint();
                        this.splash.validate();
                    }
                }
                reader.close();
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return out;
        }
```

Create a new ThreadData Object from our regex strings
This method should be rewritten, rushed job.
@param line - our line from the URL
@return new ThreadData object

```
        private ThreadData getDetails(String line){
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX_THREAD_NAMES);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
            if(matcher.find()){
                  String title = matcher.group(1);
                  pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX_THREAD_URL);
                  matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
                  if(matcher.find()){
                      String urlLink = matcher.group(1);
                        return new ThreadData(title,urlLink,getContent(urlLink)); 
                  }
            }
            return null;
        }
        private String getContent(String urlLink){
              String output = null;
              try {
            URL url = new URL(urlLink);
            BufferedReader reader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX_THREAD_CONTENT);
                   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputLine);
                    while (matcher.find()) {
                        output = matcher.group();
                        output = output.replace("<div class=\"blizzquote\">","");
                        try {
                            output = output.substring(0, output.indexOf("</div>")-1);
                        } catch (Exception e){ }
                    }
            }
            reader.close();
              } catch (Exception e){
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
            return output;
        }

    }
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/y6aDPgzW is the full source

Comment: I think this question may be off-topic because this belongs on code review